# Data loss while sending file over Java socket (android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, android-networking

i am trying to transfer large file over java socket transfer happen sucessfully but the file recieved miss some data or some bytes in my opinion. (completely new to the sockets)

**Server Side Code**

```
try {

    File img = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/abc.mkv");

    byte[] mybytearr = new byte[8192];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(img);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    long len = fis.read();

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

    int read;
    while ((read = dis.read(mybytearr)) != -1) {
        dos.write(mybytearr, 0, read);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Client Side Code**

```
try {
    if (inputStream.available() != 0) {

        int bytesRead;
        int bufferSize = 0;

        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
        String name = dis.readUTF();
        File db = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "abc.mkv");
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(db);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read;

        while((read = dis.read(buffer)) !=-1) {
            output.write(buffer,0,read);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `miss some data or some bytes in my opinion.` What is an opinion here? What is file size in bytes of original and copy? Please tell. If they differ something goes wrong. In my opinion ;-).

Comment: You forgot to tell which of the two is the sender and which the receiver of the file.

Comment: The opinion here is that the data is losding over transfer

Comment: The file size is 350mb

Comment: I asked for two file sizes. And not in MB but in bytes.

Comment: Which bytes does it miss?

Comment: Dont know about that but the file is cracked not openable

Comment: Dont know the size in bytes

Comment: And i have only one file that i am trying to send